# Quotient and remainder in Natural Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am struggling to prove the uniqueness of the quotient and the remainder in division algorithm WITHOUT using using subtraction which cannot be defined in natural numbers (and not positive integers). Common proofs that I have found presuppose the definition of subtraction. Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with subtraction? No matter what axioms of Natural numbers you start with, you can prove that for each $a,b \in \mathbb N$ with $a<b$ there is a unique $c\in \mathbb N$ such that $a+c=b$. Define this $c$ to be $b-a$.

Comment: @ashK 14 How do you define a<b? I define it in terms of the existence of a c in N satisfying a+c=b.

Comment: How do you define Natural Numbers?

Comment: Peano axioms ....

Comment: In that case, you just need to prove the uniqueness of $c$.

Comment: Since $b\neq 0,$ you have $b=b_1+1$ for some $b_1$ Then you first need to show that if $ r<b,$ then $r\leq b_1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you explain your comment somewhat more?

Comment: You almost have substraction in $\mathbb{N}$, because it is a regular monoid. For example you can say $m+n = k+n$ implies $m=k$. Or you can define $|m-n|$.